# trim last rows of a pandas dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

let's assume a dataframe like this:

```
idx  x  y
0    a  3
1    b  2
2    c  0
3    d  2
4    e  5
```

how can I trim the bottom rows, based on a condition, so that any row after the *last* one matching the condition would be removed?

for example:

```
with the following condition: y == 0
```

the output would be

```
idx  x  y
0    a  3
1    b  2
2    c  0
```

the condition can happen many times, but the last one is the one that triggers the cut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Usng **`index.max`** & **`iloc`**:

- `index.max` to get the last row with condition `y==0`
- `iloc` to slice of the dataframe on the index found with `df['y'].eq(0)`

```
idx = df.query('y.eq(0)').index.max()+1 
# idx = df.query('y==0').index.max()+1 -- if pandas < 0.25 

df.iloc[:idx]
```

**Output**

```
   x  y
0  a  3
1  b  2
2  c  0
```

---

#### Method 2:

Using `np.where`

```
idx = np.where(df['y'].eq(0), df.index, 0).max()+1
df.iloc[:idx]
```

**Output**

```
   x  y
0  a  3
1  b  2
2  c  0
```

Comment: I picked this answer because it is the most concise and clear one

Comment: your solution also picks the first occurence @Erfan, it will just grab the first true

Comment: if I'm not wrong, I guess this would just return the whole dataframe minus the last row

Comment: I'm getting an error when I run your new code for idx, you need to change `.eq()` to `==`

Comment: Which version you on? `print(pd.__version__)` @BenPap

Comment: I'm on version 0.24.2, havent updated to 0.25.0 yet

Answer (score 1):

you could do, here `np.where`returns a tuple, so we access the value of the indexes as the first element of the tuple using `np.where(df.y == 0)`, the first occurence is then returned as the last element of this vector, finaly we add 1 to the index so we can include this index of the last occurence while slicing

```py
df_cond = df.iloc[:np.where(df.y == 0)[0][-1]+1, :]
```

or you could do :

```py
df_cond  = df[ :df.y.eq(0).cumsum().idxmax()+1 ]
```

Comment: can you explain the [0][0]+1, part?

Comment: I added a brief explanation , I wish that helps

Comment: This will not work when there are more `y==0`. It will grab the first row and not the last.

Comment: oh ok didn't pay attention to that part

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
df.iloc[:df['y'].eq(0).idxmax()+1]
```

Just look for the largest index where your condition is true.

**EDIT**

So the above code wont work because idxmax() still only takes the first index where the value is true. So we we can do the following to trick it:

```
df.iloc[:df['y'].eq(0).sort_index(ascending = False).idxmax()+1]
```

Flip the index, so the last index is the first index that idxmax picks up.

Comment: Simplify this and correct it. First you need `+1`. And you don't need to specify all columns, its the default: `df.iloc[:df['y'].eq(0).idxmax()+1]`

Comment: I tested it, but that still picks the wrong index due to how idxmax works, I changed my answer to something that will always pick up the highest true index.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your dataframe:

```
data = [
    [ 'a',  3],
[ 'b' , 2],
[  'c' , 0],
[  'd',  2],
[ 'e' , 5]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x',  'y']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'idx'}).sort_values('idx')
```

Then find your cutoff (assuming the idx column is already sorted):

```
cutoff = df[df['y'] == 0].idx.min()
```

The df['y'] == 0 is your condition. Then get the min idx that meets that condition and save it as our cutoff.

Finally, create a new dataframe using your cutoff:

```
df_new = df[df.idx <= cutoff].copy()
```

Output:

```
df_new

   idx  x   y
0   0   a   3
1   1   b   2
2   2   c   0
```